# What is wrong with this csr since openssl refuses to decode it? (

Tags: bash, unix, openssl, csr

using openssl req -in test.csr -text -noout i get an error.
When i copy paste in https://www.sslshopper.com/csr-decoder.html everything works...
link to csr: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgD8LyteY-eH6TzTDa1I8YHM_8XC?e=TEfRFb
any one an idea what is wrong with the file?

Comment: It looks like all the newlines got converted to spaces. Look at it with a text editor (or just `more`) and you should see what I mean. Apparently the sshshopper decoder tolerates this, but openssl doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

your test.scr file is malformed

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST----- MIIC9zCCAd8CAQAwgbExCzAJBgNVBAYTAkJFMREwDwYDVQQIDAhGbGFuZGVyczER MA8...
```

needed

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST----- 
MIIC9zCCAd8CAQAwgbExCzAJBgNVBAYTAkJFMREwDwYDVQQIDAhGbGFuZGVyczER
MA8GA1UEBwwIQnJ1c3NlbHMxGTAXBgNVBAoMEFZsYWFtc2UgT3ZlcmhlaWQxGDAW
...
```

below, a command to replace space with NL in your file.

```
sed -r 's/(-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----|-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----|\S*)\s/\1\n/g' test.csr | openssl req -text
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Subject: C = BE, ST = Flanders, L = Brussels, O = Vlaamse Overheid, OU = Departement LNE, CN = ontwikkel.mili...
```

Comment: it is working, but not for all csr's in my list. So i think i need some extra sed help ;-) see: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgD8LyteY-eH6T0NTWb29uuOChcM?e=FwJXdH any help would be very much appreciated, i'm no sed wizard at all...

Comment: @devreebr, your question is off topic of development. 
You can try this 
```sed -r 's/(-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----|-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----|\S*)\s/\1\n/g' 5.csr```

Answer (score 0):

thank you
very much appreciated

i have about 10000 csr's to decode which were saved in a csv...